# Proof of "Every vector space has a basis $\implies$ AC" without mentioning von Neumann hierarchy

Tags: vector-spaces, axiom-of-choice, alternative-proof

I am writing a short (30-50 pages) report on AC for an exam. I really would like to include the proof that "Every vector space has a basis $\implies$ AC". Actually, every proof I could find proves that AMC (the Axiom of Multiple Choices) holds, not AC. Since ZF $\vdash$ "AC $\iff$ AMC", that would be formally fine, but then I would like to include the proof of "AMC $\implies$ AC". But every proof I could find proves it by passing through "$\cal P(\alpha)$ is well-orderable for every ordinal $\alpha \implies$ AC".

The proof of the latter seems to use von Neumann hierarchy. The professor I will present my report to is not a logician (he's an Algebra professor), and I'm pretty sure that he wouldn't like to read too much set-theory stuff.

Therefore my question is: do you know any way to prove "Every vector space has a basis $\implies$ AC" without mentioning von Neumann hierarchy?

Thanks

Comment: I think this is still open, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What do you mean precisely? I mean, in ZF every implication above is a (known) equivalence, therefore from a mathematical p.o.w. I can't see any open problem...or do you mean that it's still unknown whether there is any "shorter" proof?

Comment: You are asking "Is it true in $\sf ZFA$ that "Every vector space has a basis implies the axiom of choice". Are you not? This is a problem, and I think it is open. What else would you mean "without the von Neumann hierarchy?" Besides that, I think that you should tell your professor (in a polite way, of course) that in order to talk about linear transformations you should know some linear algebra, and in order to talk about set theoretic axioms you should know some set theory. There's ultimately no escape from that.

Comment: Probably I wasn't clear enough, sorry! I just want a proof that works in ZF but doesn't explicitly mention the von Neumann hierarchy.

Comment: I see. Okay then.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I think you're right about your comparison with linear algebra. I'll see what to do (whether to add the entire proof or leaving AMC $\implies$ AC without proof).

Comment: You should, perhaps, consult with said professor. I'd suggest adding such proof in the appendix.

Comment: Can I suggest an alternative vector space related equivalence which is vastly easier to prove equivalent to the axiom of choice? (Because to some extent it's impossible to truly avoid the axiom of regularity in a proof that existence of bases implies choice; at best we can hide it...)

Comment: Sure! You decide whether to write here or send me an email (you should have my address, I wrote you some days ago)...

Comment: Whichever you like. I'm not sure it would be fit here as an answer to this question. But this has the added benefit of built in MathJax support.

Comment: For me it's just a matter of SE rules and politeness... And you know them better than me for sure. As of MathJax rendering, I can understand directly the code. Or, if you want, you can write it in such a way it is easy to compile :)

Comment: @aerdna91: Few days back I came across the following note: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/zorn1.pdf It contains some references regarding your questions. I don't know whether it will be helpful or not (my knowledge in logic is next to zero), but you can take a look.

Comment: @Krish thank you for your answer. The linked article seems very well written, but unfortunately deals only with the inverse implication.

Comment: @aerdna91: that's true. but there are other references also. you can look at those. as I said, my knowledge is almost zero, so I can't say much about it. but the 5th reference seems to deal with the kind of things you need. again, I'm not very sure.